# Duplicate key error using nvarchar when adding new row with same number but leading 0

Tags: sql

I want to insert a row into a table where in the primary key column I have a value of `3719`. However, in the same table I want to add details with `03719` but I am getting an error:

> The duplicate key value is (3719).

The datatype of that column is nvarchar.

Comment: Edit your question and show the insert statement.  Also, tag the question with the database you are using and if possible, set up a SQL Fiddle to illustrate the problem.

Comment: Provide the sql that you have used to insert the records.

Comment: Include the error message too. And edit the question title.   (Man, this is hard work.)

Comment: Unless the INSERT statement does something weird or there's some strange condition on the column that converts values to a numeric type there's no way it should be like this if the value to be inserted and the column type are non-numeric. Leading zeroes are not removed for `nvarchar`. My best guess is you use some kind of string-concatenated INSERT statement and forgot to wrap the string value und quotes, which makes it a number.

Comment: Try this. `insert into tablename (pkcol) values('03719')` you might have missed **quotes**

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar - My guess is there's an incoming numeric parameter that's supposed to be converted to char.  Of course, there's the separate issue of prefixing with `0`s not always being a great idea...

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse Yes, that's my guess, too. Prefixing with `0` is sometimes necessary. If you want to store German post codes for example, the leading `0` may be very relevant.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar - `'3719'` vs `'03719'`?  That's an accident waiting to happen.  US postal codes can also have leading `0`s - however, note that proper representation requires that _all_ of them be present - it's `'00004'`, never `'4'` (or anything in between).

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse We don't have postal codes of varying lengths. They always need to be 5 numbers, but there may be leading zeros, that was the point I was trying to make. Of course you could store the post code as a numeric value and convert it to string by left-padding it to 5 places. I just wanted to say that these are a good example where storing a numeric value as a string with leading zeros may be important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem arises from the fact that you forgot to wrap the string value to be inserted in single quotes, so it is treated like a number, which is auto-converted to `nvarchar`.

```
INSERT INTO Table (Column) VALUES (03719)
```

is equivalent to

```
INSERT INTO Table (Column) VALUES (3719)
```

The value (because of the column type) is then converted to the string `'3719'`. Of course you then get a duplicate key error.

**Check the quotes**. If you're calling this from an application, **use parameterized queries**!

Answer (score 1):

Correct statement to insert the records is like

```
Create table test (id nvarchar(25) primary key, name varchar(20))

insert into test values('111','hello')
insert into test values('0111','hello')

select * from test
```

You're forgetting to put the quotes.
If you do not put the quotes, you will get the below kind of error

```
Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK__test__3213E83F2C904DEB'. 
Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.test'. The duplicate key value is (111).
```